# Click event is not triggering my filter function

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I'm having trouble with my click event

Below is the minimal code.

My filter function triggers on page load only.

What I'm trying to achieve is when I click on the `<li>` with the class of 'active'. The function should run and the value of the **active** li is used as the argument for the filter function, then filter the list accordingly.

```js
   

window.onload = listFilter();

const activePage = document.querySelector('.page-item.active');


activePage.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("Clicky");
  listFilter();
});

function listFilter() {
  const list = document.querySelectorAll( '.resultsItem' );
  const items = [...list];
  console.log(items);
  const itemsPerPage = 5;

  const currentPgVal = parseInt(document.querySelector('.page-item.active a').textContent);
  let rangeMax = (currentPgVal) * Number(itemsPerPage) - 1;
  let rangeMin = (rangeMax - Number(itemsPerPage)) + 1;

  for(let item in items) {
    if(item <= rangeMax && item >= rangeMin ) {
     items[item].classList.remove("hidden");
    }else {
     items[item].classList.add("hidden");
    }
  }
}
```

```css
 
  .hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
   
 <div class="list" id="resultsList">
  <div class="resultsItem">
    <p>Item 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="resultsItem">
    <p>Item 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="resultsItem">
    <p>Item 3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="resultsItem">
    <p>Item 4</p>
  </div>
  <div class="resultsItem">
    <p>Item 5</p>
  </div>
  <div class="resultsItem">
    <p>Item 6</p>
  </div>
  <div class="resultsItem">
    <p>Item 7</p>
  </div>
  <div class="resultsItem">
    <p>Item 8</p>
  </div>
  <div class="resultsItem">
    <p>Item 9</p>
  </div>
  <div class="resultsItem">
    <p>Item 10</p>
  </div>
 
</div>
        
  <ul class="paginatorList">
  <li class="page-item previous"><a onclick="createPagination(pages, 1)">&lt;</a></li>
  <li class="page-item"><a onclick="createPagination(pages, 1)">1</a></li>
  <li class="page-item active"><a onclick="createPagination(pages, 2)">2</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: `window.onload = listFilter();` <-- wrong

Comment: Thank you @epascarello for the very helpful insight...

Comment: Just remember we help for free and that code is still wrong. :)

Comment: I need this function to run on page load and also "on click". Perhaps this is somewhat confusing.

Comment: The name of the event is 'click' not 'onclick'. `activePage.addEventListener("click", function(e) {`

Comment: That code is not running onload. You are calling the function and assigning what it returns to the event listener. So in reailty you just did. `listFilter(); window.onload = undefined;` Second issue is addEventListener is wrong. Third issue, are you binding before or acter the elements are on the page?

Comment: @BrianGlaz. Yes, I saw this. This is actually a typo.

Comment: @epascarello. You are correct sir. As a side note. On page load, if I click the <li> with the "active" class it does console.log "Clicky".

Comment: So what is the variable `pages`  and createPagination? Is that code old?

Comment: @BrianGlaz no the code is evaliated when the code is encountered, not at the page load.

Comment: the onclick function createPagination is what handles the pagination format. I guess I could chain 2 onclick functions?

Answer (score 0):

Did some checking and @epascarello pointed out I already had an Onclick function. So I just invoked my filter function inside of it and my filter works great!

So for a quick overview it was :

```
function createPagination(pages, page) {
  some code
  listFilter();
  return code;
}

function listFilter() {
  code code code
}
```